# Conditional variance of a random variable conditioned on its own value

Tags: probability, variance, random-variable, conditional-probability

Suppose that $X$ is a random variable. Does it hold that $\mathbb{V}ar[X|X]=0$? What is the proof/intuition behind this?

Comment: If you condition on the value of a random variable it becomes a constant. A constant has no variability. So its variance is 0.

Comment: How much does $X$ vary when you know it's exactly $7$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intuitively there is no variance of a known quantity because it doesn’t vary; and if we condition on a RV, it means we’re *given* the RV, i.e. we know its value. If someone gives it to me, there will be no uncertainty left associated with it.

More mechanically:
$$var(X|X)=\underbrace{E[X^2|X]}_{X^2}-(\underbrace{E[X|X]}_X)^2=X^2-(X)^2=0$$

Comment: Thank you very much!